# Opening /dev/hidraw2 can hang with steamcontroller

Tags: c, linux, controller, steam

My problem is about the opening a steam controller over '/dev/hidraw2' which sometimes leads to the program to hang. My biggest problem is I don't know where to report this problem, so I am hoping someone knows where to go with this issue.

**The Problem:**
I have an arch Linux running which has a a steam controller connected to it (connected with the provided dongle).
When trying to access the device by opening '/dev/hidraw2' my program gets stuck in the "open" call. My program just doesn't return. It is also not possible to kill it with `kill -9`. The only way to recover is to restart my machine.

I reduced the problematic code to:

```
// compiled with gcc main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    for(;;) {
        printf("opening steam controller\n");
        # It doesn't return from the following open
        int fd = open("/dev/hidraw2", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK | O_CLOEXEC);

        printf("closing steam controller\n");
        if (fd != -1) {
            close(fd);
        }
        usleep(100000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To reproduce you have to plugin the steam controller dongle, start the above program and than turn on the steam controller (it doesn't hang every time, so you might need to turn off the controller and on again).

Some more information about my machine:

```
$ uname -a
Linux schenker 4.20.7-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Feb 6 18:42:40 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gcc --version                                                                                                   
gcc (GCC) 8.2.1 20181127
```

How can I investigate more about this issue? Do I have to dive into the steam controller drivers? or is it more an issue with the hidraw layer?

**Update:**

Requested `dmesg` output. It took three attempts to reproduce the error. There seems noting suspicious to me:

```
[  141.161817] hid-steam 0003:28DE:1142.0002: Steam Controller 'XXXXXXXXXX' connected
[  141.163527] input: Wireless Steam Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.1/0003:28DE:1142.0002/input/input34                                                                                                         
[  151.291873] input: Wireless Steam Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.1/0003:28DE:1142.0002/input/input35                                                                                                         
[  152.940759] input: Wireless Steam Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.1/0003:28DE:1142.0002/input/input36                                                                                                         
[  155.287349] input: Wireless Steam Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.1/0003:28DE:1142.0002/input/input37                                                                                                         
[  160.634001] hid-steam 0003:28DE:1142.0002: Steam Controller 'XXXXXXXXXX' disconnected
[  172.665613] hid-steam 0003:28DE:1142.0002: Steam Controller 'XXXXXXXXXX' connected
[  172.667006] input: Wireless Steam Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.1/0003:28DE:1142.0002/input/input38                                                                                                         
[  181.306918] hid-steam 0003:28DE:1142.0002: Steam Controller 'XXXXXXXXXX' disconnected
[  185.465807] hid-steam 0003:28DE:1142.0002: Steam Controller 'XXXXXXXXXX' connected
[  185.467249] input: Wireless Steam Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.1/0003:28DE:1142.0002/input/input39                                                                                                         
[  187.030851] input: Wireless Steam Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.1/0003:28DE:1142.0002/input/input40                                                                                                         
[  192.673722] hid-steam 0003:28DE:1142.0002: Steam Controller 'XXXXXXXXXX' disconnected
[  196.937743] hid-steam 0003:28DE:1142.0002: Steam Controller 'XXXXXXXXXX' connected
[  196.939272] input: Wireless Steam Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.1/0003:28DE:1142.0002/input/input41
```

**Update2**
Also some strace output:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/hidraw1", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
write(1, "closing steam controller /dev/hi"..., 38closing steam controller /dev/hidraw1
) = 38
close(3)                                = 0
nanosleep({tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=100000000}, NULL) = 0
write(1, "opening steam controller /dev/hi"..., 38opening steam controller /dev/hidraw1
) = 38
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/hidraw1", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC
```

This issue is not limited to hidraw2 can also happen on hidraw1 (I guess it depends on where the actual steam controller is connected to)

I also notice that when my program is stuck and I call start a second instance on a other console, it immediately hangs on the `open()` independently from the off/on state of the controller.

Comment: What does dmesg say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a bug between the hid_steam driver when interacting with acpid.

I contacted the author (Rodrigo Rivas Costa) of the driver of hid_steam, which is the right thing to do by the LKML protocol (see http://vger.kernel.org/lkml/#s2-1)

For me the short term solution is to unload hid_steam since I am accessing /dev/hidrawX directly:

```
# modprobe -R hid_steam
```

Rodrigo is already working on a patch.
A big shout out to Rodrigo for troubleshooting this so fast.
Thanks!